# Mesos Master error. Socket and zookeeper

Tags: server

I have setup mesos,zk and marathon before in ubuntu 14.04. However when I tried setting up on ubuntu 16.04.1. Whenever i start mesos master service there is problem. This error seem this always occur in `service mesos-master status`
details below

```
● mesos-master.service - Mesos Master
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mesos-master.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2016-09-28 17:07:35 MYT; 1min 12s ago
 Main PID: 7205 (mesos-master)
    Tasks: 21
   Memory: 10.4M
      CPU: 703ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/mesos-master.service
           ├─7205 /usr/sbin/mesos-master --zk=zk://10.50.1.2:2181/mesos --port=5050 --log_dir=/var/log/mesos --hostname=10.50.1.2 --ip=10.50.1.2 --quorum=1 --
           ├─7220 logger -p user info -t mesos-master[7205]
           └─7221 logger -p user err -t mesos-master[7205]

Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@726: Client environment:zookeeper.version=zookeep
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@730: Client environment:host.name=testmaster
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@737: Client environment:os.name=Linux
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@738: Client environment:os.arch=4.4.0-31-generic
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@739: Client environment:os.version=#50-Ubuntu SMP
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@747: Client environment:user.name=(null)
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@755: Client environment:user.home=/root
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@log_env@767: Client environment:user.dir=/
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,911:7205(0x7fbe50d21700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@800: Initiating client connection, host=10
Sep 28 17:08:45 testmaster mesos-master[7221]: 2016-09-28 17:08:45,912:7205(0x7fbe21ffb700):ZOO_ERROR@handle_socket_error_msg@1722: Socket [10.50.1.2:2181] zk
```

I'm not sure what went wrong because I didn't not encounter this problem before on ubuntu 14.04 setup.

UPDATE: mesos master log

```
Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
I0928 17:24:55.607309  8682 logging.cpp:194] INFO level logging started!
I0928 17:24:55.608624  8682 main.cpp:370] Using 'HierarchicalDRF' allocator
I0928 17:24:55.694563  8682 leveldb.cpp:174] Opened db in 85.440226ms
I0928 17:24:55.705240  8682 leveldb.cpp:181] Compacted db in 10.558745ms
I0928 17:24:55.705389  8682 leveldb.cpp:196] Created db iterator in 42146ns
I0928 17:24:55.705629  8682 leveldb.cpp:202] Seeked to beginning of db in 159030ns
I0928 17:24:55.705809  8682 leveldb.cpp:271] Iterated through 1 keys in the db in 91724ns
I0928 17:24:55.705924  8682 replica.cpp:779] Replica recovered with log positions 0 -> 0 with 1 holes and 0 unlearned
I0928 17:24:55.708621  8700 log.cpp:107] Attempting to join replica to ZooKeeper group
I0928 17:24:55.713376  8682 main.cpp:543] Starting Mesos master
I0928 17:24:55.717751  8700 recover.cpp:451] Starting replica recovery
I0928 17:24:55.723019  8699 recover.cpp:477] Replica is in VOTING status
I0928 17:24:55.723924  8699 recover.cpp:466] Recover process terminated
I0928 17:24:55.731030  8682 master.cpp:375] Master 12121224-5a95-4ec3-9e18-27b03896e8d5 (10.50.1.2) started on 10.50.1.2:5050
I0928 17:24:55.731158  8682 master.cpp:377] Flags at startup: --agent_ping_timeout="15secs" --agent_reregister_timeout="10mins" --allocation_interval="1secs"$
I0928 17:24:55.731812  8682 master.cpp:429] Master allowing unauthenticated frameworks to register
I0928 17:24:55.731884  8682 master.cpp:443] Master allowing unauthenticated agents to register
I0928 17:24:55.731948  8682 master.cpp:457] Master allowing HTTP frameworks to register without authentication
I0928 17:24:55.732045  8682 master.cpp:499] Using default 'crammd5' authenticator
W0928 17:24:55.732118  8682 authenticator.cpp:512] No credentials provided, authentication requests will be refused
I0928 17:24:55.732599  8682 authenticator.cpp:519] Initializing server SASL
I0928 17:24:55.754320  8699 contender.cpp:152] Joining the ZK group
I0928 17:24:55.755129  8682 master.cpp:1785] Successfully attached file '/var/log/mesos/mesos-master.INFO'
I0928 17:25:01.612355  8703 http.cpp:381] HTTP GET for /master/state from 10.50.1.201:37153 with User-Agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0)$
W0928 17:25:01.612527  8703 http.cpp:2004] Current master is not elected as leader, and leader information is unavailable. Failed to redirect the request url$
W0928 17:25:05.726553  8703 group.cpp:503] Timed out waiting to connect to ZooKeeper. Forcing ZooKeeper session (sessionId=0) expiration
W0928 17:25:05.726701  8699 group.cpp:503] Timed out waiting to connect to ZooKeeper. Forcing ZooKeeper session (sessionId=0) expiration
W0928 17:25:05.726912  8700 group.cpp:503] Timed out waiting to connect to ZooKeeper. Forcing ZooKeeper session (sessionId=0) expiration
I0928 17:25:05.727430  8700 group.cpp:519] ZooKeeper session expired
I0928 17:25:05.728480  8699 group.cpp:519] ZooKeeper session expired
I0928 17:25:05.728526  8703 group.cpp:519] ZooKeeper session expired
W0928 17:25:05.730283  8705 group.cpp:503] Timed out waiting to connect to ZooKeeper. Forcing ZooKeeper session (sessionId=0) expiration
I0928 17:25:05.733244  8705 group.cpp:519] ZooKeeper session expired
```

Update 2:
It seem that even if zookeeper is started or restarted and the status of zookeeper is running shown in "service zookeeper status", i did a netstat to check if zookeeper was listening on a port however there is none.